Implementing Fine-Grained Access Control with AuthZForce for FIWARE Services
I'm working on securing a FIWARE system (Orion, Quantum Leap) using Keyrock, Wilma, and AuthZForce. My goal is to implement fine-grained access control based on FIWARE services.
Each entity in our system belongs to a service, identified by the Fiware-Service header. I want to restrict access to these services based on user roles:
**User1**: Can only access *fiwareservice1*
**User2**: Can access *fiwareservice2* and *fiwareservice3*
**User3**: Can access all *services*

I'm struggling to create appropriate XACML policies in AuthZForce to enforce these rules. Has anyone successfully implemented a similar setup?
I'm open to suggestions if this approach is not ideal or if there are alternative methods for managing service-based access control in FIWARE.

You don't need Authzforce for this, you can use Wilma as PEP and Keyrock as IDM/PDP. In wilma you need to set the appropriate config for the  authorization.header - either NGSILD-Tenant or fiware-service - something like this:
config.authorization = {
  enabled: true,
  pdp: 'idm',
  header: fiware-service
  location: {
    protocol: 'http',
    host: 'keyrock',
    port: 3000,
    path: '' 
  },
  azf: {
    custom_policy: undefined,
  },
};

If you are using the Docker image, this is controlled by the PEP_PROXY_TENANT_HEADER env variable.
Within Keyrock you can define permissions to use the Authorization Service header, so you could have separate rules for User1, User2 and User3.

